# jsonApi value acess

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

In my angular app. I get response from an Api. The Api response is in the Json APi format with include and relationships. I have saved the data with included and Relationships in a variable. I am trying to find a particular 'type' and fetch the variable and assign it to local variable. How can i achieve this. Please guide me.

Note. How can i access the value of key "level" in included.

TS

```
this.testService.gettestdata(id).subscribe((data: any) => {
      
    this.testdata = data;
    const swords_level = data.included  // what can i do here to fetch the level value from "included" > type = skills > attributes > level.
    });
```

testdata (format of my json response saved in variable.)

```
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "characters",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {},
    "relationships": {
      "skills": {
        "data": [{ 
          "type": "skills", "id": "swords" 
        }, { 
          "type": "skills", "id": "bows"
        }]
      },
      "descriptions": {
         "data": [{ 
          "type": "skill-descriptions", "id": "swords" 
        }, { 
          "type": "skill-descriptions", "id": "bows"
        }]
      },
      }
    }
  }],
  "included": [{
    "type": "skills",
    "id": "swords",
    "attributes": {
      "level": 20
    }
  }, {
    "type": "skills",
    "id": "bows",
    "attributes": {
      "level": 3
    }
  },{
    "type": "skill-descriptions",
    "id": "swords",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Swords",
      "description": "Fighting with swords",
      "help": "This skill influences the ability to fight using a sword, both in terms of the ability to hit your opponent and to block any incoming attacks from them.",
      "icon": "http://localhost:8080/icons/skills/swords.png"
    }
  },{ ...
  }]
}
```

Comment: The `included` property is an array in which each element contains a `level` property. Do you wish to extract an array like `[20, 3, ...]` where each element corresponds to a level?

Comment: Hi, I want to extract specifically **level**  value with **type**: **skills** and **id** : **swords**.

Answer (score 2):

You could use array `filter` method on the `included` array and filter based on the `type` and `id` properties. And access the `attributes.level` property.

Note: I assume you'll have unique elements for `type` and `id` combinations. If not the resulting array will have multiple elements and I am accessing the `level` property of only the first element.

```js
var input = {
  "included": [{
    "type": "skills",
    "id": "swords",
    "attributes": {
      "level": 20
    }
  }, {
    "type": "skills",
    "id": "bows",
    "attributes": {
      "level": 3
    }
  }]
};

var output = input.included
  .filter(item => item.type === "skills" && item.id === "swords")[0]
  .attributes.level;

console.log(output)
```